# Show macOS NSWindow from inside CLI tool

Tags: swift, macos, command-line-interface

I have a CLI tool developed in Swift which does some computation. I would like to show the results of the computation in a window with a graph, therefore some UI is required,

Is there a way to "marry" these two worlds? i.e pick/input stuff in the terminal/console then get the result on demand via UI on macOS?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out https://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/01/demystifying-nsapplication-by.html and https://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, the second link is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Yet another, updated for Swift helpful article: https://theswiftdev.com/how-to-build-macos-apps-using-only-the-swift-package-manager/

Answer (score 1):

To show a window you have to import `Cocoa` or `AppKit` and launch the shared application instance with

```
NSApplication.shared
```

because a window needs access to the window server and needs also a runloop.

Then show the window for example with `NSAlert`.

The application delegate class is not mandatory.